# Aligning elements around circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment, raphael

I'm experimenting a bit with aligning elements in a circle using jQuery's cos and sin functions. The problem that I'm currently having is that my "dots" are not alligned correctly. I'm calculating the angle by dividing the number of total dots with the total - 360 deg circle radius. It's somehow causing me trouble and I can't seem to find the answer.

```
var paper = Raphael('svg', '100%', '100%');
var circles = 20;
var angle = 360 / circles;

for (i = 0; i < circles; i++) {
    var x = 200 + 100 * Math.sin(angle * i);
    var y = 200 + 100 * Math.cos(angle * i);
    console.log(angle * i);
    paper.circle(x, y, 10).attr({
        fill: 'green'
    });
}
.wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}
#svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:gray;
}
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="svg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a fiddle so we can see how, exactly, they're misaligning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Math.sin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) is working on [**radians**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), so use *2 * π* instead of *360*

```
var angle = 2 * Math.PI / circles;
```